# Xamarin ListView itemSelected MVVM

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am very new to Xamarin.Form, I would appreciate your help.

I am using MVVM pattern for my current project. I have listview populated with people, I want to select the item in list view and show the detail. Unfortunately, I could not find any example addressing this issue.

This is my Bindable Class :

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
BindableProperty.Create(
      propertyName: "Command",
      returnType: typeof(ICommand),
      declaringType: typeof(ListViewItemSelected));

public ICommand Command
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
}

protected override void OnAttachedTo(ListView bindable)
{
    base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

    bindable.ItemSelected += BindableOnItemSelected;
    bindable.BindingContextChanged += BindableOnBindingContextChanged;
}

private void BindableOnBindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lv = sender as ListView;
    BindingContext = lv?.BindingContext;
}

private void BindableOnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (Command == null)
        return;
    Command.Execute(null);
}
```

I am not sure about the next step in my ViewModel.
I created ICommand Property to exacute the method

```cs
public ICommand DetailView { get; set; }
```

In my constructor i added

```cs
DetailView = new Command(PathToDetailView);
```

I created this method

```cs
void PathToDetailView()
{
     //Which I do not know what should go here to redirect to DetailsPage for each item.
}
```

I am kind of stuck in the DetailViewPage how to get the value.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options here, but the easiest may be to bind the `SelectedItem` of your `ListView` to a property in your viewmodel

```
public Person SelectedPerson
{
  get => _selectedPerson;
  set
  {
    if(_selectedPerson == value)
    {
      return;
    }
    _selectedPerson = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] propertyName = null)
{
  PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

I've made use of [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). `INotifyPropertyChanged` will inform your view (or rather your `BindableProperty`), that a property in your viewmodel has changed and gives the view the opportunity to update the contents. `CallerMemberNameAttribute` is syntactic sugar, that lets you omit the name of the property you are calling `OnPropertyChangedFrom`. It's basically the same as if you called

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedPerson));
```

In your view, you can now bind the `ListView` to `SelectedPerson`

```
<ListView ... SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">...</ListView>
```

and use `SelectedPerson` in `PathToDetailView`.